# Access row in html table

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm using the below function (copied from this site) to delete HTML table row,

```
function delete_row(o) {

 var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
 alert(p.value)//I need to alert the value of the row 
 p.parentNode.removeChild(p);

}
```

The above function is working fine in deleting the row but what I need also is to get the text of the row/col before delete the HTML row so I can delete it from MySQL DB as well, I tried p.value and p[0].value but that didn't help and I can't find how to do that.

How can I access (row 1, cell 1) from p above for the table below (row 1, cell 2)?

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td> <img src="delete.png" name="image" width="10" height="10" onclick="delete_row(this)"> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
<td> <img src="delete.png" name="image" width="10" height="10" onclick="delete_row(this)"> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The number of levels at which it is a Bad Idea(tm) to delete a row from a database based on a clientside text field is staggering.

Comment: You are messing with your table structure by deleting nodes that way, you probably just need to empty their `innerHTML` or use other methods,again your updated question is not very clear, I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So I'm trying to first delete from DB then delete the row from the HTML table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try accessing `innerHtml` attribute :

```
alert(p.innerHTML);
```

or

```
alert(p.innerText);
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkmZu/1/)

Comment: innerText will just give you the text portion, if that's all you want

Comment: I fixed it, it was `innerHtml` and should be `innerHTML` you can take a look in the jsfiddle.

Comment: is it possible to do something like this p.firstrow.text?

Comment: there is a `p.firstChild`, I would advice you to use chrome's developer tool `F12` and then debug and see what `p` could have as function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `p.innerText` instead of `p.value`, like this:

```
alert(p.innerText);
```